# Passport-facebook authentication -Access Previous request data

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook

Iam using passport-facebook strategy for facebook authentication.

I have a form to fill in before authentication . Form data is available through req.params.all() before authentication , but when i authenticate through passport-facebook strategy , my previous req.params.all() is not available.

How can i access my previous request details (req.params.all() ie form post data) even after authentication also ?

I tried setting passReqToCallback to true , but in vain.

Any help for this is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: save the data in to a session.

Comment: Is there any other possibility ?

Comment: There are a few options to save persistent data. `Sessions` are the most obvious, but you could also save it to a file. But this is discouraged as you will start accumulating many files soon enough. Unless, you have a good way to do GC, sessions are the best way to go.